# Netezza/SQL Column Alias concatenate text with parameter value

Tags: sql-server, netezza

In the stored procedure below, I simply want to create a column alias based on a parameter value. It looks simple, but I could not find my answer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP"(INTEGER, INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
    whichyear ALIAS FOR $1;

BEGIN
    Select  x as "Some Text" + whichyear  from some table...

 ;
END;
END_PROC;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like SQL Server code.

Comment: Netezza SQL. Even if I get SQL server code for similar purpose, It can help greatly.

Comment: Well in SQL Server, you would have to use Dynamic SQL to do this.   Don't know anything about Netezza.

Comment: Thanks, would you possibly provide an example of dynamic SQL for this type of example. Netteza SQL is super similar to SQL server. I might be able to work around with it in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab is right that this would require dynamic SQL in Netezza. Here is an example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP"(INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
    whichyear ALIAS FOR $1;
    vSQL varchar(30000);

BEGIN
    drop table the_results if exists;

    vSQL := 'CREATE TABLE THE_RESULTS AS SELECT COL1 "SOME TEXT ' || whichyear || '" FROM TABLE_A;';

    execute immediate vSQL;

END;
END_PROC;
```

Here's the output.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> exec SP(5);
 SP
----

(1 row)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from the_results;
 SOME TEXT 5
-------------
           2
           3
           1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly how I should do it in Netteza. It worked perfectly :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Please mark the answer as correct if that's the case.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I am new member in Stackoverflow. Thanks for noting that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you would use dynamic sql like this:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'Select  x as SomeText' + @whichyear + ' from sometable';

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That got me closer to what I was looking for.